# SQL management doesn't run as different user after Win10 Anniversery update

Tags: windows-10, sql-server

Last night I updated Windows with the 10 anniversary update and now I am experiencing the following issue;

I right click on the SQL Management Studio 2016 and chose "Run as a different user" - after the update I cannot.

I get a popup saying this takes elevated permissions. Restart with different credentials or Cancel the task. .

I tried reinstalling that didn't solve anything

Comment: Are you connected to a Active Domain?

Comment: Would love to hear in case you find any solution to this. Not really keen on switching profiles here.

Comment: Seems like there's a bug opened over at Connect for this: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2824772/visual-studio-2015-and-ssms-2016-rtm-vs-2015-shell-not-running-under-run-as-different-user-on-windows-10-anniversary-windows-2016-ctp-5

Comment: @csrowell I am getting a page not found error on your link (I am logged in)

Comment: @JamesJenkins yeah, I see the page has been moved or deleted and I can't find a copy of it anywhere. I did find this Connect issue: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/2944134

Apparently Microsoft has fixed it for Windows 10 version 1703 but hasn't for older versions such as 1607.

Answer (score 16):

Solved it by right clicking the shortcut -> Properties -> selected Compatibility -> Change settings for all users  -> Run this program as an Administrator - and then made sure that the account that I wanted to use as "Run as" account are in the local administrators group.

Comment: thanks, this worked for me. should be the accepted answer.

Comment: I uninstalled and reinstalled SSMS 2016, ensured the the "Run as" account had local admin on the machine, before trying this fix.  This change made it work.

Answer (score 0):

Having the exact same issue but when running Visual Studio as my main account. Obviously it's some user profile corruption. In my case this also breaks Start Menu and modern apps. Maybe it's the same for your account?

As a quick and dirty solution: Create a new user to run the server as.

Comment: Answers shouldn't be used to indicate you also have the problem.  They should be used to directly answer the author's question.  Creating a new user profile, might mitigate the problem, it does not really solve the problem.  In some cases this might not even be possible, say in the case of a domain user profile, although I suppose in that case the profile could be simply removed from the machine.  This is an attempt to provide more thoughtful and polite feedback to answers like this.

Comment: @Ramhound It *is* a solution that might work, not just mitigates it. It worked in my case. I added the first paragraph as an explanation since it isn't 100℅ the exact same scenario. Of course this could be a domain thing, but then you could just clear the local copy I guess.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit of a kludge, but this works for me:

```
runas /netonly /user:DOMAIN\Administrator "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\Ssms.exe"
```

I put that command in a batch file, and run that when I need SSMS as domain administrator.